# Getting a value (on the right pane) from the registry

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, registrykey

I'm trying to get a value from the registry in Windows, which sits under several branches:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\...
```

Given the following code:

```
RegistryKey openSubKey = settings.OpenSubKey(
    @"\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\DefaultSpoolDirectory");

openSubKey.SetValue("printername", "");
```

Where settings is set to LocalMachine in `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`.

However, I'd get null after the first line of code. What gives?

Comment: This is, of course, *not* how you add a printer to a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes, \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE doesn't belong there, you should use Registry.LocalMachine instead.  And DefaultSpoolDirectory doesn't belong there, it is a value, not a key.

The SetValue() arguments do not look happy either.  If you want to add a printer (don't) then you'll need to add a key, not a value.

Comment: Good eye on the key containing a value name.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, they've helped.

Answer (score 0):

try removing "\hkey_local_machine"

Answer (score 0):

Richard's answer seems correct, but just to inform you a little further, you can access the `LocalMachine` scope of the registry through the `Registry.LocalMachine` property - check [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.localmachine.aspx) for details. For an example, try this:

```
var openSubKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers");
```